# When is the right time to meditate?

Tags: meditation-practicalities

I was watching "how to meditate" in internet. In one video, a master said, not to meditate in the night in dark. If one meditates in dark, they should light candle or incense stick. The reason he gave was, one meditating in night will be possessed by spirits. Is this true? When is the right time to meditate.

Answer (score 2):

The right time is whenever you can, wherever you are, starting if possibile with a calm mind. Try to maintain a constant practice, whichever technique do you follow. As a reminder read Webu Sayadaw's [To Light a Fire](http://www.myanmarnet.net/nibbana/webu01.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with robermann's comment, and if I am to add something to it, it is this.
We have to have a strong belief that the path to Nibbana exists in this Dhamma. One who has that confidence meditates carefully. Does it in an orderly manner. This requires some time. It does not happen in a day or two. Not in a week, in a month or two or in a year or two. We cannot restrict it to a short period.
With metta....